# access gitlab dashboard from another computer

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, headless

I am trying to setup my own gitlab server on a headless server running ubuntu. I installed gitlab using the command line. I changed the `external_url` in the `gitlab.rb` file to the ip address of the server on my network.

When I try to navigate to the ip address of my server in the web browser of another computer I cannot see the dashboard. How can I access the dashboard from another computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Configuring the external URL for GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab), make sure to run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the change to take effect.

That applies to the [Omnibus installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/), which is best done using a [GitLab docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html).

If the service answer locally (as per comments/discussion), then it is a network or firewall issue.

As how in "[How To Install and Configure GitLab on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04)", you might need to adjust firewall rules:

```
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
```

Comment: I did `reconfigure`. I also did `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`, however, I'm still not able to access the web interface from another computer

Comment: @DasPete Are you using the Docker image. For your current tests using the local server, are you using 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I'm trying to connect with another computer. So I'm using the ip address of that machine. In this case `192.168.1.41`

Comment: @DasPete Did you use a Docker image? What version of GitLab are you using?

Comment: I'm not using docker, it's jsut a dedicated ubuntu computer. I'm on gitlab version 11.5.4

Comment: > "When I try to navigate to the ip address of my server in the web browser of another computer": do you see the dashboard when testing it locally, with a curl, directly on your Ubuntu server?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, I'm not familiar with curl. It's a headless setup, so ssh is really the only access I have to the computer. It doesn't have a monitor at all.

Comment: I did try `curl http://192.168.1.41` and see some html code about logging in. So I think it is working locally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188202/discussion-between-vonc-and-daspete).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. It was a problem with the `ufw` settings. I ran `ufw allow http` and I am now able to access the dashboard

Comment: I was monitoring the discussion, without realizing you posted here! Anyway, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help! I accepted your answer